Must Teamim be followed while reciting Tehilim?
The Tehillim in my Tanakh is of course full of cantillation marks, or ta'amim. But is it necessary to follow these Ta'amim, or could the recitation of Tehillim be made with “free spirit”, so to speak. I am a student, and beginning the process of familiarizing myself with cantillation marks, particularly Moroccan ta'amim. (I am referring to the melodic aspects of ta'amim, the cantillation, rather than as a means of punctuation.

Welcome to MiYodeya Nile and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The teamim help you to interpret the text by indicating where to put a pause when necessary. If you don't respect them, your reading won't be meaningful even in prose.

Generally speaking I believe only one community actively teaches the te'amim of psalms using specific melodies and grammar, which is the Syrian community. Everyone else breaks down the psalms as a general melody and so most communities read a general melody for each pasuk.
In that vein I don't believe that Moroccans break down the Psalms by specific grammatical and musical te'amim. Instead they are like the Jerusalem Sephardic tradition, which has a way of generally reading the Psalms that is a flow but isn't that specific. In your case I don't see any issues being a little free flow
